# Why Haskell ghc does not work, but runghc works well?

Tags: haskell, ghc

One code work from runghc, but I can not compile same one with ghc command. Why?

Below is my minimal code and environment:
https://gist.github.com/1588756

Works well:

```
$ runghc cat.hs
```

Can not compile:

```
$ ghc cat.hs -o cat
```

Macbook air, max os x snow leopard

Comment: Is it `cat.hs` or `cat.cs`? Naming it as `cat.hs` and use `ghc cat.hs -o cat` works for me (on Linux).

Comment: cat.cs is my wrong naming. Rename cat.hs, then works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.cs` extension shown in your paste is wrong;<sup>1</sup> rename the file to `cat.hs` and it'll work fine.

This error message:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file cat.cs, file was built for unsupported file format
which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

occurs when you pass a file GHC doesn't know how to handle; it just passes it on directly to the linker, which then ignores it as *it* doesn't know, either. :)

<sup>1</sup> At least until GHC gets C# support...

Answer (score 4):

With the filename `cat.cs`, on linux I get

```
$ ghc cat.cs
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:cat.cs: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:cat.cs:1: syntax error
```

So indeed, since GHC doesn't know how to handle `.cs` files, it passes them as is to gcc for linking, gcc doesn't know either, so falls back to regarding it as a linker script, which of course doesn't turn out so well.

But you can tell GHC that it should treat whatever file you give it as, say a `.hs` file,

```
$ ghc -x hs cat.cs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( cat.cs, cat.o )
Linking cat ...
```

`runghc` on the other hand doesn't care what the file is named, it tries to interpret the file as normal Haskell source, except if it has the extension `.lhs`, then it tries to interpret it as literate Haskell.